# Using specific firefox profile of Tor instead of Torbrowser

Tags: tor, firefox

I create a dedicated profile in Firefox for tor (with `firefox -no-remote -p`) and configure it to use specific network setting with Edit > Preferences, Advanced > Network > Settings

And then:

```
manual proxy configuration:
http proxy           port: 0
ssl proxy            port: 0
ftp proxy            port: 0
socks host 127.0.0.1 port: 9050
```

In addition, I use the plugins [NoScript](https://noscript.net/) and [HTTPS Everywhere](https://www.eff.org/https-everywhere/), as Torbrowser do.

But, when I open https://check.torproject.org/ with this Firefox’s profile, I get :

> Congratulations. This browser is configured to use Tor.
>
> **However, it does not appear to be Tor Browser.**

So, there is a real reason to use Torbrowser instead of my dedicated Firefox’s profile system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Tor Browser is not only a Firefox with some safe settings. The Tor Project maintains many patches which enhance the privacy, but which Mozilla doesn't include in their software.

So you won't be able to have an own browser similar to Tor Browser just by changing settings and using plugins.

Answer (score 5):

One major feature of the Tor browser is that it (mostly) avoids browser fingerprinting. By default they all have the same fonts, screen-size, supported extensions ect. With other browser you can often uniquely identify them, see https://panopticlick.eff.org/ for a demonstration. The fingerprint can then allow that user to be tracked, both when using Tor and when not.

Comment: I see. But there is not a set of recommendations to _anonymise_ a browser like TorBrowser do? I try to rebuild the behaviour of TorBrowser with another browser.

Comment: @fauve, it is hard to do because all it takes is a single missed item to make your browser unique. For example my Tor browser warns me if I go full screen as I may be the only Tor browser with that screen resolution (extremely unlikely but possible). I would recommend checking out the panopticlick link included in my answer and trying to minimize your bits that leak. However even with a 0 leak you will likely be more unique then Tor browser.

Comment: I understand, so, yes I tryed your link. And I get two bad items:

Is your browser accepting Do Not Track commitments?  ✗ no

Does your browser protect from fingerprinting?  ✗ no

But I try to fix it :)